# Which option (out of three) is more appropriate?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have a list of colours. I would like to name that list. I find myself unsure which of the following is more correct:

1. Colours names
2. Colour names
3. Colours' names

Comment: For the name of a list, option 2 is best.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could u please shed some light on 1 and 3 options? Can we use these two in any context?

Comment: You might use "The colours' names" in a sentence. "The colours' names are not standard ones.", for example. I don't see much use for 1, unless "colours" is a verb. "The software colours names of variables according to their type."